# Determining function from simple xy graph

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, data-analysis

I'm not sure if this question is too vague for here. Will delete if necessary.

I have a set of points, (1,782), (2,893), (3,992),... and I'm trying to determine the function that was used to generate them.

When plotted on a graph, it looks a lot like `y = sqrt(x) * a + c`, or something like `y = Log(x - a) + c`, but I've been playing around in excel, and these aren't quite right. I've also experimented with other roots, and not made progress.

Are there tools or methods I can use to get a better approximation, or any simple functions that I've overlooked?

```
1   782
2   893
3   992
4   1081
5   1164
6   1241
7   1313
8   1382
9   1447
10  1510
20  2031
30  2444
40  2796
50  3108
60  3392
70  3653
80  3897
90  4127
100 4344
200 6106
300 7462
400 8607
```

(The `y` values have been rounded to integers).

Comment: I don't know much about this, but as my memory serves me [Lagrange polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Have you tried linear regression; maybe non-linear regression?

Comment: Some [results](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=best%20fit%20%7B%7B1,%20782%7D,%20%7B2,%20893%7D,%20%7B3,%20992%7D,%20%7B4,%201081%7D,%20%7B6,%201241%7D,%20%7B8,%201382%7D,%20%7B10,%201510%7D,%20%7B20,%202031%7D,%20%7B40,%202796%7D,%20%7B60,%203392%7D,%20%7B100,%204344%7D,%20%7B200,%206106%7D,%20%7B300,%207462%7D,%20%7B400,%208607%7D%7D) using Alpha.

Comment: and the [best fit of $(\sqrt{x},y)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=best%20fit%20%7B%7B1,%20782%7D,%20%7BSqrt%5B3%5D,%20992%7D,%20%7B2,%201081%7D,%20%7BSqrt%5B6%5D,%201241%7D,%20%7BSqrt%5B8%5D,%201382%7D,%20%7BSqrt%5B10%5D,%201510%7D,%20%7BSqrt%5B20%5D,%202031%7D,%20%7BSqrt%5B40%5D,%202796%7D,%20%7BSqrt%5B60%5D,%203392%7D,%20%7B10,%204344%7D,%20%7BSqrt%5B200%5D,%206106%7D,%20%7B20,%208607%7D%7D) (better).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni. The simple fit `y = sqrt(x) * a + c` shows already a correlation coefficient equal to 0.9994 which is more than sufficient I guess. Nice to meet you here !

Comment: @Claude: You are right but small values may be important too (the OP will at least have some choice !). I somewhat enjoy to guess answers as you may see in my [graphing-functions tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:21783%20%5Bgraphing-functions%5D). All the best and excellent continuation! Cheers,

Comment: @Marc thanks for the Lagrange polynomial tip. I will investigate...

Comment: @RaymondManzoni thanks for the link! WA never ceases to amaze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple and accurate solution could be : $$f(x):=\sqrt{432718+184284\;x}$$
\begin{array} {c|cc}
x&y&f(x)\\
\hline\\
1& 782&785\\
2& 893&895\\
3& 992&993\\
4& 1081&1082\\
5& 1164&1164\\
6& 1241&1240\\
7& 1313&1313\\
8& 1382&1381\\
9& 1447&1446\\
10& 1510&1508\\
20& 2031&2029\\
30& 2444&2442\\
40& 2796&2794\\
50& 3108&3106\\
60& 3392&3390\\
70& 3653&3651\\
80& 3897&3896\\
90& 4127&4125\\
100& 4344&4343\\
200& 6106&6106\\
300& 7462&7464\\
400& 8607&8611\\
\end{array}

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To me, `y = sqrt(x) * a + c` seems to be very good in particular for large values of `x` (above `x=25` the fit is excellent). To me, the real question is : what do you want to do ? If it is interpolation, I think that Lagrange polynomials (as suggested by Mark) would be the best idea since there is no much noise in your data. If it is extrapolation for values such  `x > 400` , I suppose that the above regression would be very reasonable [in such a case, fit your data for, say, `x > 50`]. Where I see problems is for low values of `x`; but here again, I should use  Lagrange polynomials.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I took another look at square roots and tried to make them fit better but it's never perfect. I'm trying to interpolate the missing values for `0 < x < 500`. I believe the underlying function should be very simple. I'll try Lagrange polynomials and see if anything simple drops out...